# MongoDB $lookup on nested document and prepare result as required

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections one is permissions and another one is roles. Now I need to retrieve data from these two collections through the join by permission object ID, my query is working good but can't get result as required. Collections details are given below.

**permissions:**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b4998d4abb4369f8c1ad0d6"),
"roleName" : "Super top level",
"permissions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b49982d34f95d80609ce99d"),
        "access" : [ 
            "view_graph", 
            "view_daily_trip", 
            "view_profit"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b49982d34f95d80609ce99e"),
        "access" : [ 
            "view", 
            "add", 
            "edit", 
            "delete", 
            "special", 
            "disable"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b49982d34f95d80609ce99f"),
        "access" : [ 
            "trip_view", 
            "trip_add", 
            "trip_edit", 
            "trip_delete", 
            "trip_special", 
            "trip_disable"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

**roles:**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b4998d4abb4369f8c1ad0d6"),
"roleName" : "Super top level",
"permissions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b49982d34f95d80609ce99d"),
        "access" : [ 
            "view_graph",
            "view_daily_trip",
            "view_profit"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b49982d34f95d80609ce99e"),
        "access" : [ 
            "view",
            "add",
            "edit",
            "delete"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b49982d34f95d80609ce99f"),
        "access" : [ 
            "trip_view",
            "trip_add",
            "trip_edit"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

**Required result:**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5b4998d4abb4369f8c1ad0d6",
    "roleName": "Mid level",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "_id": "5b49982d34f95d80609ce99d",
            "access": [
                "view_graph",
                "view_daily_trip",
                "view_profit"
            ],
            "permissionGroups": "Dashboard",
            "allAccess": [
                "view_graph",
                "view_daily_trip",
                "view_profit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5b49982d34f95d80609ce99e",
            "access": [
                "view",
                "add",
                "edit",
                "delete"
            ],
            "permissionGroups": "User",
            "allAccess": [
                "view",
                "add",
                "edit",
                "delete",
                "special",
                "disable"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5b49982d34f95d80609ce99f",
            "access": [
                "trip_view",
                "trip_add",
                "trip_edit"
            ],
            "permissionGroups": "Trip",
            "access": [
                "trip_view",
                "trip_add",
                "trip_edit",
                "trip_delete",
                "trip_special",
                "trip_disable"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I've tried a lot using `$lookup, $unwind, $project` and `$group` but nothing gave-me that result.
Can you please help me to write the exact query ? Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks:)

Comment: Your both the collections have same JSON? Which is the common key in both?

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet, Not actually that, it depends on the  role, some role will contain all access string and some role will few and both has a common object ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Its worked for me !**

db.collection('roles').aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$permissions" },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "permissions",
            localField: "permissions._id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "permissions.permissionObj"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "roleName":1,
            permissions: {
                "_id":'$permissions._id',
                "assignPermission":'$permissions.access',
                "groupName": {
                    $arrayElemAt: [ '$permissions.permissionObj.permissionGroups', 0 ]
                },
                "allPermission": {
                    $arrayElemAt: [ '$permissions.permissionObj.permissions', 0 ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            roleName: { $first: '$roleName' },
            permissions: { $push:  "$permissions" }
        }
    },
    { $sort:{ _id:1 }}
]);
```

Comment: Could you pls help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109179/mongodb-find-deeply-nested-object-with-lookup?noredirect=1#comment108111460_61109179