# MongoDb: find deeply nested object with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this: 
collection name is - account. 
and it has sub-documents like account > buildings > gateways > devices.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1fe45cd05bfb0cc549297d"),
    "apiCallCount" : 0,
    "email" : "info@data.com",
    "password" : "dummy",
    "userName" : "AAAAA",
    "companyName" : "The AAAAAA",
    "apiKey" : "5e1fe45cd05bfb0cc549297c",
    "solutionType" : "VVVVVV",
    "parentCompany" : "",
    "buildings" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e1fe5e3d05bfb0cc5494146"),
            "buildingName" : "xxxxxx",
            "address" : "xxx",
            "suite" : "101",
            "floor" : "22",
            "timeZone" : "us/eastern",
            "gateways" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1fe624d05bfb0cc549453a"),
                    "gatewayName" : "CC-GW-THF-001",
                    "gatewayKey" : "gk_5e1fe624d05bfb0cc549453a",
                    "suite" : "area1",
                    "devices" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5e1fe751d05bfb0cc549578d"),
                            "serialNumber" : "129300000013",
                            "area" : "area1",
                            "connectionStatus" : 1,
                            "gatewayKey" : "gk_5e1fe624d05bfb0cc549453a",
                            "applicationNumber" : 30,
                            "firmwareVersion" : "1.0",
                            "needsAttention" : false,
                            "verificationCode" : "GAAS",
                            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T04:32:17.899Z"),
                            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T08:53:54.460Z")
                        }
                    ],
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T04:27:16.678Z"),
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T08:53:54.460Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1fe651d05bfb0cc54947f0"),
                    "gatewayName" : "AA-GW-THF-002",
                    "gatewayKey" : "gk_5e1fe651d05bfb0cc54947f0",
                    "suite" : "area2",
                    "devices" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5e1fe7a9d05bfb0cc5495cdf"),
                            "serialNumber" : "129300000012",
                            "area" : "area2",
                            "connectionStatus" : 0,
                            "gatewayKey" : "gk_5e1fe651d05bfb0cc54947f0",
                            "applicationNumber" : 30,
                            "firmwareVersion" : "1.0",
                            "needsAttention" : false,
                            "verificationCode" : "VG3K",
                            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T04:33:45.698Z"),
                            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T08:54:17.604Z")
                        }
                    ],
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T04:28:01.532Z"),
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T08:54:17.604Z")
                }, 


            ],
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T04:26:11.941Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T08:56:32.657Z")
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-16T04:19:40.310Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-04-06T18:18:39.628Z"),
    "__v" : 1,
}
```

I have accountId, buildingId, gatewayId, deviceId.
I am trying to find matched device object using $lookup operator.

I think I have to fist find the building object by using buildingId and then filter gateway under that building using gatewayId and then find device object using deviceId that I have.

**I basically need to have access to device object fields to project in final output.**
Having difficulty in coming up with correct pipleline for usingg lookup operator.

I have this so far:

```
    db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {

        from: 'account',
        let: {
            accountId: "$accountId"
        },
        pipeline: [

            {
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$eq": ["$_id", "$$accountId"]
                    }
                }
            },
        ],

        as: "accountDetails"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$accountDetails"
}, {
    $lookup: {

        from: 'account',
        let: {
            accountId: "$accountId",
            buildingId: "$buildingId",
            buildings: "$accountDetails"
        },

        pipeline: [

            {
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$eq": ["$buildings._id", "$$buildingId"] // how to dig through nested document to get to devices ? 
                    }
                }
            },
        ],

        as: "buildingDetails"
    }
}
          {
            $project: { ... ... 
              }
        ])
```

if I do this:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'account',
        localField: "accountId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "accountDetails"
    }
},
```

***accountDetails*** gives me access the account document based on accountId. but I need to get to buildings > gateways > devices and find the matching device.

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention, I am working with 2 collections here. 
sensingresults and accounts.

Main purpose is to aggregate data from sensingresults, but also find deviceId from account collection and return with the result.

That's why lookup is needed to join 2 collections?

UPDATE2:

Current output:

```
  {
    "accountId": ObjectId("5e1fe45cd05bfb0cc549297d"),
    "avgZoneCountNumber": 0,
    "avgZoneCountNumberInstant": 0,
    "buildingId": ObjectId("5e1fe5e3d05bfb0cc5494146"),
    "companyName": "The AAAAAA",
    "createdAt": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "dateHour": "2020-03-19T18",
    "deviceId": ObjectId("5e1fe81ed05bfb0cc5496406"),
    "gatewayId": ObjectId("5e1fe6a6d05bfb0cc5494d25"),
    "minuteBucket": 1
  }
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "accountId": ObjectId("5e1fe45cd05bfb0cc549297d"),
    "avgZoneCountNumber": 0,
    "avgZoneCountNumberInstant": 0,
    "buildingId": ObjectId("5e1fe5e3d05bfb0cc5494146"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "dateHour": "2020-03-19T18",
    "deviceId": ObjectId("5e1fe81ed05bfb0cc5496406"),
    "gatewayId": ObjectId("5e1fe6a6d05bfb0cc5494d25"),
    "minuteBucket": 1,
    "serialNumber: 1, // this value should come from device object 
    "area": 1  // this value should come from device object 
  }
```

Comment: Please format the code block properly

Comment: I formatted and also updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find nested `device` using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) and [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html):

```
device: {
    $let: {
        vars: {
            building: { 
                $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$company_name.buildings", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$buildingId" ] }} }, 0 ] 
                }
        },
        in: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    gateway: {
                        $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$$building.gateways", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$gatewayId" ] }} }, 0 ] 
                    }
                },
                in: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$$gateway.devices", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$deviceId" ] }} }, 0 ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Full Solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_ePHUedJiAL)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am working with 2 collections here. 
sensingresults and accounts. 

Main purpose is to aggregate data from sensingresults, but also find deviceId from account collection and return with the result. 

That's why lookup is needed to join 2 collections?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VV_9sBp57M4 I added my original aggregation, note that first lookup is simply getting companyName from account. I need to dig through account and get device object using those ids that I have.

Comment: @newdeveloper can you show the data as well? Mongo Playground can take handle more than one collection, there's an example when you click "docs"

Comment: I created 2 collections - https://mongoplayground.net/p/iV7mdIL_-qv its throwing an error but I think its just not getting the collection name, you will know i think

Comment: @newdeveloper that's fine (https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q18TMiaLAuk), now I need to understand what is your expected output. The question you've asked says you need to find deeply nested object so how does that adhere to this aggregation?

Comment: I have updated the question (UPDATE2) final output needs some fields from device object (like serialNumber, area)

Comment: ignore companyName in final result from demo playground. (it was put just to illustrate the lookup join)

Comment: @newdeveloper thank you, this helps, check out my modified answer